# Display event in a cell that starts at midnight (night shifts)

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

Good afternoon,

I´m developing a calendar using FullCalendar scheduler and my client needs to see night shifts of a date that starts beyond 00:00 of the next day. I already know that `nextDayThreshold` allows to display events that occurs between two days establishing a time end limit but FullCalendar displays an event in the next day when it starts at 00:00.

One solution could be to create non standard Event fields like `realStart` and `realEnd` to store real dates and using start and event standard fields for visual representation but it has many unwanted effects. Ideas please?

Comment: Can you give a concrete example to make this clearer? Are you saying that if a shift starts at 01:00 on Thursday morning, that your client wants to see it listed on Wednesday? What view are you using (e.g. timeline, agenda), and how detailed is it (e.g. 1 day per slot, or 1 hour per slot, etc)?

Comment: That’s exactly what my client wants. I’m using `timelineMonth` view. I ran out of ideas on this.

Comment: Sounds like a timeline is not really the right place for that kind of information. A timeline shows events at the time they actually occur. Maybe they just need a summary in a "list" style view of events which occur within a custom duration. I dunno, I'm not sure how you'd really support that in a "calendar" environment unless you change the definition of a "day". Sounds like their business practices are based on doing exactly that.... you might just have to generate some separate list outside the confines of fullCalendar.